# JavaScript: Save .csv inside folder with todays date

Tags: javascript, node.js

Everyday I run shell script to create New Folder with current date.

With Shell it is super easy to save anything within that folder, even if folders name often changes.

E.g.: `currentDate=/path/$(date +%Y%m%d)` I just put a `date` variable within the `Path`.

I thought, it would be similar with JavaScript?

So the question is, is there a way within JavaScript syntax, to access the folder whose name changes constantly?

The below doesn't seem to work:

```
// Create the log file with Today's Date
folderName = "~/Desktop/"

var now = new Date();
var logfile_name = now.getFullYear() + "-"+ now.getMonth() + "-" + now.getDate()

var fileOut = new File(folderName+logfile_name+"/"+'RT3.csv');
if (!fileOut.exists) {
  fileOut.open("w");
  fileOut.writeln(",", docRef.name);
} else {
  fileOut.open("a");
  fileOut.writeln(",", docRef.name);
}

fileOut.close();
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'd need Node.JS for that at the very least.

Comment: @JackBashford i don't think so since all he had to do was checking if folder exist or not and then create csv on according folder adn then add .psd names into csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it should create Current dated folder on desktop and should add your current document name on .csv**

```
var folderName = "~/Desktop/";
var now = new Date();
var logfile_name = now.getFullYear() + "-"+ now.getMonth() + "-" + now.getDate();
var f = new Folder(folderName + logfile_name);
if ( ! f.exists ) {
    f.create();
}
var docRef=app.activeDocument;
var file = new File(f+"/"+'RT3.csv');
file.open('w');
file.writeln(",",docRef.name);
file.close();
```

The thing you missed is i think checking for folder if it exist or not :) anyway enjoy!

Edit : and well you don't even have to use shell to create folder since this photoshop script will automatic does it if it not exist :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for!! Thank you! I just had to change variable `logfile_name` as: `var logfile_name = now.getFullYear() + "-" + 0 + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + 0 +now.getDate();` to output YYYY-MM-DD format. Thank you once more!